# Lubavitch and Daf Yomi

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, chabad, daf-yomi

I know that *most* lubavitchers won't learn Daf Yomi.

Is there any Sicha (please bring sources) which says if one should or shouldn't learn it?

Comment: Won't, like they refuse? Interesting, I was not aware of that.

Comment: You know that they _won't_, or that they _don't_?

Comment: -1, until you bring proof that the initial statement is true.

Comment: You personally know MOST Lubavitchers, and what they learn? The Rebbe never endorsed Daf Yomi but he wasnt against it, and you certainly will not find a sicha from the Rebbe saying a person should not learn Torah.

Comment: We are trying to invalidate Lubavitch or validate Daf Yomi? What about Satmar and Daf Yomi? What about Lakewood and Daf Yomi? You think a true litvak supports learning Gemara on the level that isn't even girsa?

Comment: @mochinrechavim I can't say that I know **all** Lubavitchers, but in all Yeshivas I attended, there was not even a mention of anyone doing Daf Yomi (not bachurim, not Hanhala, not as an "out of seder" limud, there was no signs as to the current daf. It was as if it didn't exist.) My question is whether this is a "sourced" hergesh (The Rebbe said that "we **don't** do it - like learning Zohar legirsa) or is it just a "chassidishe hergesh [as in it's not our thing - like "Kitzur Yomi" (which I am almost sure that the Rebbe never talked about)])?

Comment: @AdamMosheh personal experience - see previous comment.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Why would bochurim be learning daf yomi? They are not the target audience of this learning program. The short answer, is you will not find a sicha of the Rebbe telling Chassidim not to learn Daf Yomi, you will have one about L'Girsa Zohar, which is a little more obvious of a reason.

Comment: @mochinrechavim many learn gemara lagirsah.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin While the Rebbe Rashab might disagree, there is nothing wrong with learning gemara l'girsa in Lubavitch per say. This is beside the point as the original question has no constructive response other then being critical that Lubavitch doesn't "support" a system of learning that just brought almost 100,000 Jews together in New York.

Comment: ShmuelBrin, in _y'shivos_ I've been in (none of them Lubavitch), no one learned _daf yomi_. As @mochinrechavim says, "They are not the target audience of this learning program".

Comment: @Shmuel I suggest changing the word "won't" to "don't", in the absence of evidence otherwise, and as that may be the cause of some of the question's unpopularity.

Comment: Many of the Lubavitchers I know learn Daf Yomi.

Comment: right now there is a "daf yomi" style learning that is built into what chabad learns. During sefira many learn a page a day of sota up until shavuos. the sefira being 49 days and the mesechta being 49 pages makes this like the daf yomi schedule for this art of the year

Comment: real litvaks also don't do daf yomi. daf yomi is a modern creation. while in one way it is a positive way to increase learning in general 1. it's arbitrary to simply say to learn exactly 1 daf no more and no less. 2. it's b'kius and the ideal way to learn Talmud is by learning in a more thorough way.

Comment: why ask specifically about Lubavitchers? daf yomi is a relatively new practice all together. It's not accepted by litvaks either who emphasize learning b'iyun not just finishing an arbitrary amount just to get through it for the day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I heard (no source) that when asked once the Rebbe said Daf Yomi is not a "davar Hashaveh lcol nefesh" (something that would apply equally to everyone) unlike the shiurim in Chumash, Tehilim, Tanya and Rambam.

However, it should also be mentioned that Lubavtich has its own (older) tradition from the Alter Rebbe (subsequently printed in Igros Kodesh of Tanya) about dividing and partnering everyone in learning Gemara, where everyone takes a different misechta and learns it through the year (this division was initially done on Yud Tes Kisleiv, subsequently moved to Chof Dalet Tamuz, and since moved back to Yud Tes Kisleiv), where everyone in the group becomes a partner and with their learning their part, they become a partner in the whole Shas every year.

Promoting Daf Yomi would be promoting a different system where one person would have difficulty doing both and the Rebbe very much promoted the maintenance and strengthening of Chabad customs among Chabad Chassidim.

Of course the Siyum Hashas was a wonderful thing, and although I avoid trying to project what someone would have said as it tends to just be wishful thinking on the part of the speaker, it is quite imaginable that the Rebbe's reaction to the Siyum would have been to praise it and point that it is a lesson to strengthen and encourage the custom of dividing Shas according to the Alter Rebbe's system as well.

Answer (score 8):

Since Daf Yomi is printed in the weekly [Dvar Malchus](http://dvarmalchus.org/) booklet -  It's very unlikely that the Rebbe opposed learning it.

Comment: Is Dvar Malchus (not the 5752 sichas) printed by Kehos?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Good point. I've always taken it for-granted that it was was from Kehos (probably because of the fact that the front cover uses the same cover as the original dvar malchus - with the Kehos logo) - but now that you mention it - I'm not sure. I just looked at a booklet now, and I can't make out who the publisher is. I think I'll edit the Kehos bit out of the answer in the mean time though. Thanks.

Comment: Its not printed by Kehos, rather by a separate print house https://dvarmalchus.org/                                                         it only uses the kehos logo because it copies the cover page formats of the Sichos of the Nun years which were called "Dvar Malchus" in fact there are seforim out called Dvar Malchus which collect all those sichos.

Answer (score 7):

While the Rebbe did not openly endorse Daf Yomi, there is no sicha of (because this is the antithesis of) the Rebbe telling Chassidic dafka not to learn Gemara in this way.

The fact that there were a dozen or so high profile Rabbonim representing Chabad at the recent Agudath Israel of America daf yomi siyum, is clear that Lubavitch supports any and all forms of Torah learning:

> COLlive.com has learned that Philanthropist R' Sholom Yehuda Rechnitz, a donor and emcee of the celebration, personally invited Rabbi Yehuda Krinsky, the Rebbe's Mazkir and Chairman of Merkos L'inyonei Chincuh, to join.
>
> Rabbi Krinsky, Rabbi Moshe Bogomilsky, were seated on the second row on the dais which featured some 500 rabbonim and roshei yeshiva.
>
> Other Chabad dignitaries that were identified by one attendee on stage were 770 Rosh Yeshiva Rabbi Zalman Labkowsky, Dayan Rabbi Shlomo Segal, Chevra Shas shul Rabbi Mottel Gurary, and Congregation Beis Shmuel Rabbi YY Jacobson.
>
> In the large crowd were spotted Rabbi Chaim Miller, author of Kol Menachem publications; Long Island Shliach Rabbi Anshelle Perl who gives a Gemara shiur at Chabad of Mineola; and R' Shlomo Aron Holtzberg who gives a Daf Yomi shiur at Congregation Anash at 770 Montgomery Street.

—[COLlive.com](http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=21206)

I recalled reading somewhere that at least one member of the Crown Heights Beis Din was also.

Answer (score 4):

There are Lubavitchers who do Daf Yomi, but I assume your question is why it isn't emphasized to learn Daf Yomi in Chabad. I believe the answer to your question is that Chabad has its own daily studies to do, like chumash, tehillim, Tanya, rambam. When a Lubavitcher does all those and has extra time, then he goes on to Daf Yomi, but he starts off with his own minhag which is the primary focus

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for the idea. I recommend you [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features — and I hope you stick around! (You may also wish to [choose](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/2582) a more meaningful username than "user2582".)

Answer (score 2):

I question the basis for saying that most Lubavichers don't learn Daf Yomi. If, as indicated in the comments, this is based on your years in Yeshivah, then you've answered your own question: Daf Yomi is not part of any mainstream Yeshivah curriculum.  It is, rather, a tool to encourage widespread Talmud Torah among the public not (or no longer) in Yeshivah.

You can most certainly find Daf Yomi classes taught in Chabad houses all around the world.

Comment: "You can most certainly find Daf Yomi classes taught in Chabad houses all around the world." How do you know?

Answer (score 1):

As a Toras Emes alumnus I can say that we don't participate in it mainly because it was invented by Aguda leaders who were not in favor of the central importance of Lubavitch in the Jewish world.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that all Chabad learning cycles are limited to 1 year or less (save for one exception). Keeping to a yearly cycle would seem logical as most of Judaism revolved around the a yearly cycle.

**Chumash** - follows the parsha of the week and completes in 1 year

**Tehilim** - Finished monthly

**Tanya** - Was divided by the Rebbe Rayatz to be learned on a yearly cycle

**Hayom Yom** - A 1 year calendar (the 1st book published by the Rebbe).

**Torah Ohr/Likutei Torah** - Also known as the "Chassidish Parsha" is formatted around the parsha of the week. So technically it can be learned in 1 year. (if I remember correctly, when the Rebbe gave out L'chaim at shabbos Farbrengens to those who learned the Chassidishe Parsha, only those that actually finished the portion would have the audacity to count themselves in)

**Rambam** - The Rebbe instituted a learning cycle for the Rambam to be finished in 1 year, by learning 3 chapters a day. The Rebbe also said that if that is not possible for someone to learn 3 chapter they can learn 1 chapter and finish in 3 years. This seems to be the only exception for a learning cycle to be longer than a year.

**Sefer Hamitzvos** - Learning sefer Hamitzvos - for those that do not learn the above mentioned Rambam cycle (such as children). This is a yearly cycle as the mitzvos of the day follow those that are learned in the 3 chapter cycle above.

**Tanach** - In Hayom Yom - 19 adar 1 - it states that "ordinary" Chassidim finished the entire Tanach every 3 months.

**Chalukas Hashas** - As explained in a previous answer, the corpus of the Talmud was divided amongst a community, so that everyone shared in the learning. This was a yearly cycle as well.

**Hemshechim** - With the exception of 2 (samach-vav, eiyin-bais) possibly 3 (basi ligani is a hemshech?) hemsheichim, none of them were extended over a year (I can be wrong, as I've not learned the entire body of Chabad Chassidus)

**Yeshiva Mesechta** - The Mesechta of Gemorah that the Chabad Yeshivas learn is different every year.

It would seem that Chabad focuses on finishing or just limiting a cycle within a year. There can be many reasons. I don't know of any official ones, but there are some common sense ones. Such as, if someone "falls off" the learning train, they can easily get motivated to start again in the next cycle. Another reason, a commitment for 1 year is a log easier to keep to than one that is longer. And others reasons you can probably think of.

Comment: "most of Judaism revolved around the a yearly cycle" I don't know how you can say that. We also have daily cycles and weekly cycles and monthly cycles and triannual cycles and heptannual cycles and 50-year cycles.

Comment: Clarification - "most of Judaism revolved around the a yearly cycle" -

Comment: 1. When the torah references a date it is mostly in the context of day+month+year. The year being the anchoring date. 2. Tri-annual, Shmita, and yovel are still an **"annual"** cycle. (and start on Rosh **Hashanah**) 3. Bar-mitzvah - when a person obligated - 13 years, not 156 months, or 4680 days (approximate). or 1 6/7th of a shmita. 4. The cycle of yomim tovim occurs once in a year. 5. Chabad (context of the question) teaches that the renewal of G-d's _desire_ to sustain the world is on an annual basis (avodah of Rosh Hashana) not daily, weekly or tri-annually.

Comment: 6. Months are inter-dependent on the specific year that it is in,  i.e. 2 Adar months, or if the month should be 29 or 30 days. 7. When I said "most of Judiaism" what I meant was in the context of _years_ the one year cycle is the dominant one as outlined above. The context was not in days vs months vs years. But all this detracts from the purpose of the answer. Which is to illustrate the importance of the yearly cycle over any other type.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that someone saw a hashmata from a sicha that the Rebbe said that since the Freierdiker Rebbe didn't tell buchurim to learn, this means that it is undesirable to do [there are 2 girsaos 1) its klipa and 2) tachlis hashlila]. hashmata are parts of a sicha (talk) which aren't printed in the main text of the talk, klipa is a force of evil, tachlis hashlila means completely shunned

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya bachur!

Comment: Maybe you can answer other questions tagged [Chabad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chabad)

Answer (score -1):

When The Rebbe said (mi pi shemua) that daf yomi is not Davar Hashave lkol nefesh" it was before the appearance of the artschroll Gemara
Now daf yomi is printed in the Davar malchus ( official publication) because it became hadavar Hashave lkol nefesh ( even more than the Rambam)
It's easier to get more Tora understanding now from daf yomi in artschroll than in any Rambam in English

Comment: Dvar Malchus isn't official.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, and it isn't printed with the artscroll translation either.

Comment: https://dvarmalchus.org/Download/0AFDD709-9DC2-4BA6-B05D-E1E41973B088.pdf here is a link of the dvar malchus it has "KEHOT" in the cover which is the publishing division of Chabad Lubavitch if there is a political issue in if it is official or not, I dunno

Comment: The cover was originally used for the sichos published in 5751-5752 called "Dvar Malchus" (which is why the date on the bottom says 5752). I don't know what connection the new publication has to do with those sichos.